# TypeError: Return argument type bytes32 is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment

I have one issue while deploying the below contract.could anyone help me to find the issue as unable to find issue.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract Lottery {
    address payable[] public  players; // dynamic array with players addresses
    address payable public manager; // contract manager

    // contract constructor, runs once at contract deployment
    constructor() public {
        // the manager is account address that deploys the contract
        manager = msg.sender; 
    }

    // this fallback payable function will be automatically called when somebody
    //sends ether to our contract address
    function () payable external {
        require(msg.value >= 0.01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender); // add the address of the account that                                     
                                  // sends ether to players array
    }

    function get_balance() public view returns(uint) {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        return address(this).balance; // return contract balance
    }

    // returns a very big pseodo-random integer no.
    function random() public view returns(uint256) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players.length)); <--error is this line
    }

    function selectWinner() public view returns(address) {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        uint r = random();
        address payable winner;

        // a random index
        uint index = r % players.length;
        winner = players[index];

        // transfer contract balance to the winner address
        winner.transfer(address(this).balance);

        players = new address payable[](0); // resetting the players dynamic array
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type cast your randomized result to uint256 `uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty,block.timestamp, players.length)))` as 
`keccack` returns `bytes32` output and you are returning `uint256` from your function, also you are collecting output in `r` which you've declared `uint` maintain some datatype consistency in your code. Also you've declared `selectWinner()` as *view*, which it is not, as you are changing state and making a transfer.